# Как сделать рейтинг товаров на js?

Tags: javascript, css, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть рейтинг в виде гистограммы в правом верхнем углу, слева от иконки поиска. Я не понимаю, как я должен его реализовать. Можете сделать свою иконку, свои карточки товаров, если вы понимаете как такое сделать или хотя-бы написать как называются такие скрипты, я пока-что только понял, что это гистограмма(

Comment: Находите иконку и пихаете в свой сайт. Первый поиск выдал [вот такие](https://icons8.ru/icons/set/%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0). Думаю, если поискать, надете нужную, может свою нарисуете, может вам дизайнер покажет, где он это взял...

Comment: Иконка у меня есть, просто я не пойму, что нужно сделать с ней. Поиск и переводчик по бокам работают, и эта иконка нужна зачем-то. Этот сайт я для портфолио пишу, в тг нашел, так что дизайнера нету.

Comment: То есть поиск и переводчик я уже написал, понятно для чего они, а как это должно быть реализовано, я не понимаю.

Comment: Никто, кроме вас, не знает, зачем вам эта кнопка и что она должна делать или не делать ¯\\(ツ)/¯

Comment: То есть получается я уже знаю зачем мне эта кнопка, и что она должна делать на сайте? Зачем я тогда задаю вопрос?

Comment: @ДенисКлимат спрашивать наверное стоит дизайнера либо того, кто эту кнопку придумал, на Ваш вопрос нельзя дать объективный ответ. И не совсем понятно, почему Вы решили что здесь подходящее место для этого вопроса.

Comment: Солидарен с вами, но сайт с тг для портфолио и для практики, поэтому узнать откуда ветер дует не получится. Может сам что-нибудь додумаю или пойму. Всё-таки каждый может оставить своё субъективное мнение

Comment: Если хочется, напихайте туда графики изменения(динамики) цен, спроса на товары, рейтинги по отзывам. Есть еще радикальный вариант - просто уберите этот значек из дизайна и сразу проблема будет решена )

Comment: Вопросы ответы на каторые могут быть основаны на субъективных мнениях, а не фактах, здесь обычно закрывают)

Comment: Зависит от определения

Comment: То есть ответы на вопросы должны быть основаны на субъективных или объективных фактах?

Comment: @ДенисКлимат [Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: первый же запрос "aerounion" в гугле, третья ссылка - https://aero-union.ru/
под той иконкой сравнение моделей вертушек по ттх.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы для открытия макетов используете фигму, то нажмите сочетание клавиш shift+d и найдите необходимый компонент, и нажмите на глазок в меню слева, и тем самым удалите контент.